# MacBook Pro case that ventilates and protects against dust

Tags: macbook-pro

I like to use my MacBook remotely and therefore I need to leave it standby. I normally put away my MacBook in a slipcase. I guess this isn't a good idea when I use the MacBook (remotely) because of the heat and necessary ventilation.

Are there any solutions for using a MacBook remotely and still be able to protect it against dust? Some sort of a case that has ventilation?

Comment: Would a dock help you out? There is no case which will keep your Macbook 100% dustfree and the ability to cool it. It's physically impossible..
Check these hard-cases - as they prevent your macbook from scratches for example: http://www.macbook-case.com/p/6/13-cases-macbook-pro/

Comment: Even if you remove the dust once a year, this is not an issue. Unless you work in the desert.

Comment: I was thinking of some sort of box instead of a case. Something like once used for letterwheel printers (protect against sound not dust ...). Guess such thing doesn't exist, but couldn't resist to try anyway ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [possible solution](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1012474-REG/macally_proshell13_clear_protective_case_for.html) for you.

Normally you would not need additional (forced) ventilation since MacBook does that as long it gets fresh air access.

> Product Highlights
>
> ```
> Protects from Dust & Scratches
> Access to Ports & Sensors
> Two-Piece Snap-On Design
> Ventilated Opening Minimizes Heat
> Scratch-Resistant Hard-Shell
> ```